# Show popup window for visible spots on globe

Tags: webgl, three.js

I have a globe, similar to http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_trackballcamera_earth.html.
My globe has some spots on different locations (f.ex. Paris, Rome or London). Whenever one of these spots come into view, a popup window with additional information to that location should popup appear, and again disappears when that spot rotates out of view, quite similar to http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/cloudglobe/.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3D coordinates of those points and you need to transform(rotate or whatever) them with globe. Then use this code http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code to get screen space coordinates  of those points. After that it is simple question of HTML, CSS and some javascript. You know where they are on screen so, for example,  you can put some absolute positioned divs with text. But you will need to check on which side of globe those spots are - use rotation phase of the sphere or z-coordinate of the point or simple do [color-based picking](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/2220) to see if this spot is visible.